# Switch classes with different html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have 2 types of interation: one with buttons that specify time and one with polygons on a map. I need to be able to click on a polygon and then select the time and show its relative results and vice versa click on a time button then on a polygon and get its relative results.

After a select both time and location, i need to run an action which triggers a click: `jQuery.fn.almTriggerClick();`

The code which loads the content has some meta_values which I get from both the polygon and the time buttons each time I click.

I need also the possibility of doing the interaction right but if I click outside the panel with the content loaded, the panel hides and the content disappears and run again the logic with different buttons and polygons interaction.

I wrote the following but I can't get my head around and it's buggy.

Also the buttons click must have its own function while the click I generate for the polygons must have its own. Both the buttons and the polygons must add/remove an `.active class` each time.

This is what I've got:

```
// Simplified HTML:

<button type="button" class="1600">1600</button>
<button type="button" class="1500">1500</button>

<div id="map">
   <path class=""></path>
   <path class=""></path>
</div>

// Set the initial vars

var mapClick = false;
var btnClick = false;
var date;

// JS for the buttons logic:

jQuery("button").on("click", function(b) {
    if(jQuery(".panel_block").is(":visible")){
        jQuery("#map .active").removeAttr("class", "active");
        jQuery(".panel_block").hide();
        jQuery("#ajax-load-more ul").empty().attr("data-meta-value", " ");
    }; 
    date = jQuery(this).attr("class");
    if(mapClick == true) {
        jQuery("#ajax-load-more ul").attr("data-meta-value", loc + ":" + date);
        jQuery(".panel_block").show();
        jQuery.fn.almTriggerClick();
    } else {
        jQuery("#map .active").removeAttr("class", "active");
        jQuery("#map ." + date).attr("class", "active leaflet-interactive "  + date);
        btnClick = true;
        alert("Choose location");
    }
});

//JS to handle the polygons logic

var loc;
function panelShow(e) {
    if(jQuery(".panel_block").is(":visible")){
        jQuery("#map .active").removeAttr("class", "active");
        jQuery(".panel_block").hide();
        jQuery("#ajax-load-more ul").empty().attr("data-meta-value", " ");
    };
    loc = e.target.feature.properties.name;
    jQuery("#ajax-load-more ul").attr("data-meta-value", loc + ":" + date);
    this.getElement().classList.add('active');
    if(btnClick == true) {
        jQuery(".panel_block").show();
        jQuery.fn.almTriggerClick();
    } else {
        alert("Choose time");
        mapClick = true;
    }
}

 //JS for the polygon click:

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        click: panelShow
    });
}
```

Meta values to replace each time:

```
<div class="panel_block">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more post_type="post" pause="true" meta_key="country:year" meta_value="LOCATION:TIME" meta_compare="IN:IN" meta_type="CHAR:CHAR" meta_relation="AND" button_label="SPIMEING"]'); ?>
</div>
```

The above output:

```
<ul id ="ajax-load-more" data-meta-value="LOCATION:TIME"></..
```

**NOTE:** the ID `#ajax-load-more` is attached to the html output i get from the php function, that's the element where I will change the meta_values

Comment: Have you tried to **initialize** both `btnClick` and `mapClick` variables at the top of your script to false? I did some tests and the **if statements** might **fail** because of this.

Comment: @PierreC. apologies, forgot to add the initial vars on the question. Updated now.

Comment: Well I guessed that after posting my comment... Do you have any errors in the console? I am not sure to really understand what is not working. Could you summarize the problems at the end of your post or directly in your code?

Comment: @PierreC. i could provide you with a link if you prefer as i cannot reproduce it in a JSFiddle

Comment: @PierreC. but basically if start to click this and that and try different back and forward by clicking the logic, it breaks

Comment: Well a link could be useful because it is hard to figure out the problem without testing.

Comment: @PierreC. it should also add an .active class to the polygon and button*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127426/discussion-between-pierre-c-and-rob-m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

```
var mapClick = false;
var btnClick = false;
var date;
var loc;

jQuery("button").on("click", function(b) {

    if(jQuery(".panel_block").is(":visible")){
        jQuery(".panel_block").hide();
    }; 

    date = jQuery(this).attr("class");

    if(mapClick == true) {
        mapClick = false;
        var $shortCode = '<?php echo do_shortcode("[ajax_load_more post_type='post' pause='true' meta_key='country:year' meta_value='Nicaragua:1200' meta_compare='IN:IN' meta_type='CHAR:CHAR' meta_relation='AND' button_label='SPIMEING']"); ?>'

        $('.panel_block').html($shortCode);

        jQuery(".panel_block").show(function(){
            jQuery(".ajax-load-more-wrap ul").attr("data-meta-value", loc + ":" + date);

        });

        setTimeout(
            function() {
                if ($(".ajax-load-more-wrap").length){
                    $(".ajax-load-more-wrap").ajaxloadmore();
                    $.fn.almTriggerClick();
                }
        }, 500);

    } else {
        jQuery("#map ." + date).attr("class", "active leaflet-interactive "  + date);
        btnClick = true;
    }
});

function panelShow(e) {
    jQuery("#map .active").removeClass("active");
    this.getElement().classList.add('active');

    if(jQuery(".panel_block").is(":visible")){
        jQuery(".panel_block").hide();
    };

    loc = e.target.feature.properties.name;

    if(btnClick == true) {
        btnClick = false;
        var $shortCode = '<?php echo do_shortcode("[ajax_load_more post_type='post' pause='true' meta_key='country:year' meta_value='LOCATION:TIME' meta_compare='IN:IN' meta_type='CHAR:CHAR' meta_relation='AND' button_label='SPIMEING']"); ?>'

        $('.panel_block').html($shortCode);

        this.getElement().classList.add('active');
        jQuery(".panel_block").show(function(){
            jQuery(".ajax-load-more-wrap ul").attr("data-meta-value", loc + ":" + date);

        });

        setTimeout(
            function() {
                if ($(".ajax-load-more-wrap").length){
                    $(".ajax-load-more-wrap").ajaxloadmore();
                    $.fn.almTriggerClick();
                }
        }, 500);

    } else {
        mapClick = true;
    }
}
```